# Is it possible to prevent SIGINT breaking for a code section?

Tags: python, signals

I'm working with a python script that writes to a file some longish lines of text. For further processing, it is critical that these lines are either fully-written, or skipped entirely. Setting aside possible crashes, which are not likely enough to make them worthy of special attention in-code, I would like to make the writing section "atomic"* w.r.t. SIGINT signals, so that if I need to stop the program at any point via Ctrl+C, I won't have partially-written lines in the file.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31983497/python-script-avoid-quitting-when-ctrl-c-is-pressed) that replaces the signal handler. I thought I could install a temporary signal handler at the beginning of the "critical section" (e.g., before `file.write(my_long_text_line)`) and restore the original one at the end (plus some bookkeeping for handling SIGINTs received in the critical section), but that would be a lot of swapping handlers, so I was wondering if there's a better way to achieve this.

---

*: "atomic" meaning "If I send SIGINT while inside this section, the signal will be handled once the code section is completed", I'm not interested in concurrency-related issues.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to install a different handler for `SIGINT` each time you write. Blocking and unblocking `SIGINT` around your critical section should suffice.

The following demonstrates how to achieve that.

Note that once `SIGINT` is unblocked, it'll be delivered to the process if it was received during the critical section i.e. when it was blocked. If multiple `SIGINT` signals were received, only one will be delivered after unblock.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import os
import signal
import time

def do_something(line):
    try:
        signal.pthread_sigmask(signal.SIG_BLOCK, [signal.SIGINT])
        # Critical section
        #
        # Uncomment the following 2 lines to verify that SIGINT is indeed blocked
        # print("Waiting in the critical section...")
        # time.sleep(30)
        print("Signal SIGINT is blocked here: " + line)
    finally:
        signal.pthread_sigmask(signal.SIG_UNBLOCK, [signal.SIGINT])

def main():
    print("start")
    do_something("some line")
    print("done")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I'd suggest restoring the signal mask to its original state rather than simply SIG_UNBLOCKing.  (An admin might deliberately run the process with an inherited mask, e.g.)

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping to find! Thanks, I'll give it a try as soon as I have a chance :)

Answer (score 0):

For a simple, dirty solution:

```py
try:
    do_your_stuff()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    do_closing_action()
```

I would suggest using a counter to track the current line being written, then upon Ctrl-C, check if the line has been written, write it if not, then call `exit()`

Comment: My problem is, however, how to avoid partial lines. The counter leaves me vulnerable to interrupts in the `write` (although using two counters, e.g., `lines_started_writing` and `lines_terminated` incremented before and after the write might allow me to detect partial lines & reduce the critical window enough to make it acceptable. I'll try this out). Still, I wonder if there's some language feature or module that helps with this kind of situation.